# accessing extra memory by linux guest in kvm

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu, kvm

i am running a linux guest on top of qemu -enable-kvm. I am trying to create a back channel between linux and qemu using a known physical memory location. In order to use a memory address that the kernel will never allocate to anybody, i have started the guest using 1024M physical ram. In guest, i am trying to access the 2GB th byte (2*1024*1024*1024). 
On recompiling the kernel, i am not able to boot in the new kernel again.

my code is as follows ..

```
/** in context_switch() function of  kernel/sched.c */
#define PID_ADDR ((int *)((unsigned long)2 * (unsigned long)1024 * (unsigned long)1024 * (unsigned long)1024))
int* pid_addr = phys_to_virt(PID_ADDR);

*pid_addr = next->pid //next is the task-struct ptr of the next process that is going to run.
```

can explain me how does kvm use the physical memory allocated to the guest ??

Comment: I think that what you want is not possible without changes on kvm. Take a look at: http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~puru/courses/spring11/cs620/references/kvm.pdf

Comment: @PeterSenna thanks for the link. Though I had a look at this thing earlier I will have another go at it. Meanwhile I have found a hack for doing this. qemu allows something like qemu_ram_alloc and qemu_register_io_memory. It seems I can use this functions to my advantage.

Comment: ram_addr_t pp=qemu_ram_alloc(NULL,"mydevice_sidecore",0x8000);
cpu_register_physical_memory(0xf4340000,0x8000,pp|IO_MEM_RAM);

Comment: Below is the exact code that i used :                       ram_addr_t pp=qemu_ram_alloc(NULL,"mydevice_sidecore",0x8000);
cpu_register_physical_memory(0xf4340000,0x8000,pp|IO_MEM_RAM);         Above code first allocs a ram of 32768 bytes and then attaches it at 4G mem location. We must ensure that the physical memory that qemu guest gets must be smaller than this. The second function uses required kvm functions when enable-kvm is used. If not, qemu does internal book-keeping and provides the linux guest with the required abstraction.